# How to route correctly when an argument is passed in a function?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I have a route:

```
Router::connect('/restaurants/*', array('controller'=>'restaurants', 'action' => 'view'));
```

that when a user accesses site.com/restaurants/Seafood, they get a list of seafood restaurants.  Well, the problem is, now I want to add an edit function in my controller, and site.com/restaurants/edit/4 routes to the view function of my controller.  How do I tell my routes to send /restaurants/edit to the edit() function?

I understand after the fact that the greedy star was a bad idea, but I didn't know how to make my function for view() work correctly without it.  Here is my view code:

```
public function view($type=null) {
$this->set('title', $type.' restaurants in and near Gulf Shores');
$this->paginate['Restaurant']=array(
   'limit'=>9,
    'order'=>array(
        'id'=>'asc'
        ),
    'joins' => array(
         array( 
           'table' => 'cuisines_restaurants', 
           'alias' => 'CuisinesRestaurant', 
           'type' => 'inner',  
           'conditions'=> array('CuisinesRestaurant.restaurant_id = Restaurant.id') 
         ), 
         array( 
           'table' => 'cuisines', 
           'alias' => 'Cuisine', 
           'type' => 'inner',  
           'conditions'=> array( 
               'Cuisine.id = CuisinesRestaurant.cuisine_id'
               )
           )
      )
    ); 
$this->set('restaurantType',$this->paginate($this->Restaurant, array('cuisine_type'=>$type)));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a low number of controllers where you need to implement this functionality, you can do it the "quick 'n dirty" way, i.e. explicit routes:

```
Router::connect('/restaurants/edit/*', array('controller'=>'restaurants', 'action' => 'edit'));
```

(make sure to put this line above your greedy one in routes.php)

If you need this functionality for many controllers and actions, then more versatile routing would make more sense.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that one already, and it kills any requests to /restaurants/Seafood (or any other restaurant type).  It routes to the edit() function instead.

Comment: I figured it out!  My beforeFilter() function wasn't including any of my views.  Your extra greedy star advice helps in my site security too, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way to do routings like that:

```
Router::connect(
    '/restaurants/:type',
    array('controller'=>'restaurants', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        'pass'=>array('type'),
        'type'=>'regexHere'
    )
);

Router::connect(
    '/restaurants/edit/:id',
    array('controller'=>'restaurants', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        'pass'=>array('id'),
        'id'=>'[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

Another bright side to this way is that you can route according to the regular expression, so if someone tries to access yourwebsite/restaurants/edit/notanumber won't be routed into the edit page.